# PHP Detect page open via WebView

Tags: javascript, php, webview

I've a web page that has to be opened only via mobile app with `webview` (or anything the OS uses).

I found some answer where people say to use `HTTP_USER_AGENT` to check where the request come from, but user-agent is easy editable during the request, so I'm looking for a safer way to do this.

What could be the best approach in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a small mobile app which would only run on the mobile phones that you intend to support and the app would generate some temporary tokens and would POST them to the server. The session in the mobile browser would be registered to a WebSocket channel of the server and would update those tokens in real-time. This way, at least the given app is guaranteed to be run on a phone. And if the app is tied to a single session, then it is highly probable that the session would run on the same phone.

If you want to guarantee it, then you can create a browser extension which would communicate directly with your phone app on OS level.

Comment: I don't get a lot this: "The session in the mobile browser would be registered to a WebSocket channel of the server and would update those tokens in real-time.". Are you saying i would have to open a websocket port for every app opened? Isn't possible someone find that token?

Comment: @LandL yes, it would make sense to do it. If it's not feasible for some reason in your case, then you can link your mobile app to a browser extension that you would use and ensure the communication on OS level. As about token theft, that's always a possibility, just like password or session id theft. What you can do is to ensure that the token is temporary and that the communication channel you use to transmit it is secure, preferably encrypted.

Comment: Well, this app wil lbe for android and ios so i don't think it's flexible the browser extesion. I would have to mantain two extensions  (1 for android-webview and one for ios-webview) and would be a pain. I understand you idea and i think it could work. Another thing, do you think it could be possible to achive this idea using session, cookies, http-post or other kind of things?

Comment: @LandL you can achieve this that way as long as you have an app. The app would send some requests periodically to refresh the token and the session associated to that app session would "know" when to request a new token (for example weekly). Since the app is guaranteed to run on a mobile and is entangled to a single session, this would enforce the use of as many mobile phones as the number of sessions. This would not 100% achieve the user to be using a phone, but it would make it unfeasible. Pairsed with browser agent it would be unfeasible and difficult.

Comment: I see, thank you for your explanation. Another thing, how would you associate the page opened with the token? For example: 1) App generates the token and send it to the server 2) Webview loads https: //<url>/<page> 3) Server receives a request to open this page. To do this, the webview has to pass with GET/POST the token to do the first association with the server...or i'm missing something? Anyway i take this like accepted answer.

Comment: @LandL your approach is feasible, but I would associate the session with the token, so, if a session was validated once, then it is unnecessary to validate it again when the page is revisited. You can associate the page with the token as well, of course.